# Вычислить произведение элементов с индексами, являющимися степенью 2

Tags: c#

Есть массив из 10 int чисел нужно вычислить произведение элементов с индексами, являющимися степенью 2.
Написал вот такой код, но он вычисляет что значение равно 0, хотя нулей там нигде нет. Массив заполнен пользователем через Textbox.
Неиспользованные переменные будут нужны для следующего задания.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] md = { };
        int[] M = new int[10];
        int inputCount = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int min1 = int.MaxValue;
        int min2 = int.MaxValue;
        int min3 = int.MaxValue;
        double sumabs = 0;
        int mul = 1;
        double multavg = 1;
        int A;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int A;
            if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out A) && inputCount < 10)
            {
                M[inputCount] = A;
                inputCount++;
                label3.Text += A.ToString() + ", ";
            }
            int idx = 1;
            while (idx < M.Length)
            {
                mul *= M[idx];
                idx *= 2;
            }
        }
        public void Res()
        {
            label3.Text += "\r\n" + "Произведение элементов с индексами, являющимися степенью 2: " + mul.ToString();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputCount >= 10)
            {
                Res();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если `d` в интервале от 0 до 10, зачем проверять степень двойки больше 3?

Comment: В следующем задании массив будет динамическим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно сравнивать целое число с чёрт знает чем. И вообще не надо проверок индексов - достаточно просто пройти по нужным индексам. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/z0wX3C)

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(){
        int[] M = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int mul = 1;
        int idx = 1;
        while (idx < M.Length) {
            mul *= M[idx]; 
            idx *= 2;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(mul);
    }
}

>> 270
```

Comment: Выглядит правильно, но получаю всё равно 0, едиснтвенное место где еще трогаю переменную mul это при выводе результата: 
label3.Text += "\r\n" + "Произведение элементов с индексами, являющимися степенью 2: " + mul.ToString();
Где тогда может быть ошибка?

Comment: Привёл реальный рабочий код. Где ошибка - не могу знать, кода же не вижу.

Comment: Добавил код целиком, можете глянуть?

Comment: Нужно провести дебаг и убедиться в содержимом массива. Сейчас я вижу, что вводится **одно** число, и после этого проводится обработка **всего** массива - а остаток же нулями может (или должен) быть заполнен. Либо вводите список чисел, либо обрабатывайте только после заполнения всего массива (if inputCount)

Comment: Зачем генерировать массив индексов, если можно просто использовать for?

Comment: Всё верно, забыл поставить условие что массив уже заполнен. Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy А кто массив индексов генерирует?

Comment: @MBo, ну так а зачем его хранить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Кажется, я понял, в чём недопонимание. `М` - массив данных

Comment: @MBo, да.. что-то я только описание прочитал и неправильно его понял...

Comment: *Не нужно сравнивать целое число с чёрт знает чем.* - хочу футболку с такой надписью